# botframework v4 - Use the latest Nuget package

Tags: c#, botframework

When creating a new `botframework v4` project, the latest preview version of the Bot builder on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/4.0.1-preview) dates back to the 5th of May 2018. But the repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet) is way more up to date.

Therefore, how can I build my bot using the latest preview version? Should I clone the git repo and build it myself or is there's another way via Nuget to get the updated package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bot framework V4 has been released publicly and out of beta as of today, September 24th 2018. You can update to the newest package via Nuget.

Answer (score 1):

It is still in preview. But if you click `include prerelease` you will get the needed packages [image]

Comment: Yes this is what I did, but this Preview version is the old one dated back to May 5th.

Comment: Then you need to wait them for publish new version to nuget or build it by yourself